# Using JMeter with ASP .NET MVC 4 web app returns 500 status error when logging into web app. Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jmeter, token

I'm using JMeter to load test my web app. I created two HTTP Requests, one visit login page and the other, log into my account. The visit login page HTTP request works fine and returns 302 Found status. JMeter displays the login page and there 0% errors on that page.

However, when I try to login into my account using the POST Data I retrieved from Firebug POST, it doesn't work and returns a 500 status error.

I am having difficulty getting the logging into my account feature to work. I have tried to send a POST request with the following:

1) __RequestVerificationToken
2) languageDropDown (My web app requires it) 
3) UserName
4) Password

but I am still getting the error.

I followed this tutorial as it's the only one on ASP.NET MVC web apps...

http://build-failed.blogspot.pt/2012/07/load-testing-aspnet-mvc-part-3-jmeter.html

But I didn't do the feedback form data because I don't need it. Just grab the general concepts and regular expression from that webpage and tried it on my app but it fails.

Why? How do I fix it?

Is it because I have cookies to store session and only unique users can login my web app at one time? I did add a cookie manager though.

BTW, this is on a deployed web application (not localhost).

Some photos, I blocked out all sensitive information (sorry) and some of the token's (Just in case?)
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have static authentication token? May it dynamic? 
Look at [second video](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/80479-how-to-use-jmeter-for-login-authentication) that deals with token at 5:37 min to understand how to extract dynamic authentication token.
Exept HTTP Cookie manager, try to add HTTP Cache manager

Comment: What's the difference between static and dynamic tokens? What would be useful about adding a cache manager? Thanks!